# angularjs ngRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

ngRoute not working while no errors are reported to console .

given no errors to console, how is it possible to follow execution of ngRoute procedures ?

i saw examples using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true), i don't understand when that should be used but i don't think it is required to make ngRoute work.

index.html has navigation links and ngView :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"> </script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"> </script>
  <script src="main.js"> </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Main">
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#content/first"> first partial </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#content/second"> second partial </a> </li>
</ul>
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js defines the router and the controllers :

```
var Main = angular.module('Main', ['ngRoute']);

function router($routeProvider) {

 var route = {templateUrl: 'partials/default.html'};
  $routeProvider.when('', route);

  route = {
    templateUrl: 'partials/first.html',
    controller: 'first'
  };
  $routeProvider.when('content/first', route);

  route = {
    templateUrl: 'partials/second.html',
    controller: 'second'
  };
  $routeProvider.when('content/second', route);
}

Main.config(['$routeProvider', router]);

Main.controller('first', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];
});

Main.controller('second', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [1,2,3];
});
```

partials simply make use of ngRepeat:

```
<header> First content </header>
<p ng-repeat="iter in list">
  first
</p>
```

solved : 
my problem was that my whole application is located under /ang/ prefix, and after adding that prefix to urls now it is working . 
shouldn't there be a way to use relative urls ? i guess there should and i will try to fix it .

the problem is NOT with the different syntax as everyone suggested, and that is alarming to the fact many JS developer do not in fact understand the one line syntax that they are using everywhere .

Comment: `<a href="#/content/first">` check like this

Comment: no, using #/content/first didn't make it work .

Comment: I don't see where are you calling your controller inside your html...

Comment: the controller shouldn't be called inside html since it is done using $routeProvider "when" clause .

Comment: You are missusing the `$routeProvider`, why don't you just follow the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code
HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js"> </script>
  <script src="script.js"> </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Main">
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#/content/first"> first partial </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#/content/second"> second partial </a> </li>
</ul>
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Js file

```
var app = angular.module('Main', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider.
      when('/content/first', {
        templateUrl: 'first.html', 
        controller: 'first'
      }).
      when('/content/second', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html',
        controller: 'second'
      }); 
}]); 

app.controller('first', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];
});

app.controller('second', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [1,2,3];
});
```

first page HTML

```
<header> First content </header>
<p ng-repeat="item in list">
{{item}}
</p>
```

here is your working code [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/P9iO0p6J7kmHiRGHE2Ya?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Do not reuse the route object as it might cause problems. Consider using it in the form (as suggested by the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example ):

```
$routeProvider
   .when('content/second', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/second.html',
    controller: 'second'
});
```

If you want to debug the routes that angular goes through, you might want to look at angular's interceptors: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Also, `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is not needed to make ngRoute work. It is simply a way of defining how the URLs should look like and work. in HTML mode you can change the links to not use # anymore and simply be `www.yoursite.com/app/content/second` instead of `www.yoursite.com/app#content/second`

Comment: changed code so that different route objects are used for each when clause .
i disagree with how JS developers write single line code, it is bad practice in my opinion .

Answer (score 0):

your route configuration is not correct, you assume `route` function is execute for each and every link u click but its not.

so your `route` function should be like

```
  function router($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider.
      when('/content/first', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/first.html',
        controller: 'first'
      }).
      when('/content/second', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/second.html',
        controller: 'second'
      }).
      otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'partials/default.html'
      });
  }
```

note that urls should be like `<a href="#/content/first">` // note the slash after #

to match that the routes in `route` function should be like `when('/content/first', {` note the leading slash

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HqQFXi4dt9D3XHVmaHTh?p=preview)

Comment: Isn' that just a copy of what I just wrote?

Comment: lol, noo, do u have `router` function, check the `otherwise route` check the `when URL`

Comment: @Kutyel: I could ask you the same thing :)

Comment: i am looking at your Plunker example to discover my problem, but the different syntax should not make a difference only that my version has better code readability .

Comment: because JS method of one line nested objects makes it difficult to follow code blocks .
the nesting brackets can confuse people .

Comment: my problem was that my whole application is located under /ang/ prefix, and after adding that prefix to urls now it is working .
shouldn't their be a way to use relative urls ? i guess there should and i will try to fix it .

Comment: lol, then you have specify `route,route1,route2` diferently http://plnkr.co/edit/dIEf2B5Ln8wEPXAIWwot?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Define your Routes in **routes.js**

```
var route = angular.module('route', ['ngRoute']);

route.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller : 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller : 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when("/product", {
            templateUrl: "views/product-info.html"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo :'/'});
});
```

Attach the router to your Main Module.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['route']);
```

Import both the scripts in your **index.html**